# WPF Listbox Item: Set forecolor of first item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a WPF ListBox binded to a class. As below

```
   public class MyClass
   {
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public string Gender{ get; set; }
   }

  ObservableCollection<MyClass> myData= new ObservableCollection<MyTable>();
  myClassList.ItemsSource = myData;
```

And I have the XAML as:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="userData">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3,0,3,0" Height="60">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <wpfgeneralcontrols:TextControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Style="{StaticResource SmallTextControlStyle}"
                 TextAlignment="Left" Margin="0"/>

      <wpfgeneralcontrols:TextControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Gender}" Style="{StaticResource SmallTextControlStyle}"
                 TextAlignment="Left" Margin="0"/>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>


  <ListView Name="PatientsList" Background="Transparent"  BorderThickness="0"
           Width="700" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           ItemTemplate="{StaticResource userData}"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Visible" />
```

How can I set the foreground color of only the **first item** (not the selected item) of the ListBox? I have seen some ideas on approaching this but could not adapt it to setting the foreground color of the first item in the listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in pure XAML - XAML is a *markup* language and not a programming language - but you could handle the `Loaded` event of the root `Grid` in your `ItemTemplate` programmatically:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="userData">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3,0,3,0" Height="60"
          Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                   TextAlignment="Left" Margin="0"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Gender}"
                   TextAlignment="Left" Margin="0"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

---

```
int n = 0;
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (n++ == 0)
    {
        Grid grid = sender as Grid;
        foreach (var tb in grid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>())
            tb.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
        grid.Loaded -= Grid_Loaded;
    }
}
```

I assume that your custom `TextControl` has a `Foreground` property. In the above sample code I have used `TextBlocks`.

And this does not break the MVVM pattern. It is perfectly fine to implement *view-related* logic in the view, where it belongs.

Comment: I tried it but I got an error: Cannot implicitly convert 'System.Drawing.Brush' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'. Tried to do a conversion but didn't work

Comment: So why are you using a System.Drawing.Brush? What's the type of your TextControl's property?

Comment: Check my edit. Just replace "System.Windows.Media" with "System.Drawing" if you are using a WinForms brush for some reason.

Comment: The update you provided works fine now. I also replaced the TextBlock with my custom TextControl. Perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

If your items are not null you can use `PreviousData` to detect the first item.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="userData">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource userData}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it did not work.